# How can the cognitive distortion "disqualifying / rejecting the positive" be overcome?

Tags: clinical-psychology

Within Cognitive Behavior Therapy (CBT) there is a cognitive distortion named ["disqualifying the positive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion#Disqualifying_the_positive) where positive events are discounted:

> Example: Upon receiving a congratulation, a person dismisses it
>   out-of-hand, believing it to be undeserved, and automatically
>   interpreting the compliment (at least inwardly) as an attempt at
>   flattery or perhaps as arising out of naïveté.

Other examples include:

- That compliment doesn't count. They don't know me yet.
- They are only talking to me because they think me to be something I'm not.
- I got this achievement. Big deal. Anyone else could get it.
- He/she gave me this gift. It's useless like all other gifts I get.

How can this distortion be overcome?

Comment: @StevenJeuris Hey Steven, this is off-topic. I noticed my previous question and it has killed all my hopes that my question would ever get answered. Any suggestions that you have (or anyone else) is welcome.

Comment: This site is _still_ beta, as was it when you asked the first question, thus some questions unfortunately do tend to go unanswered. As it is phrased now though it is much better than the last question (which I deleted for you). Perhaps you have more success this time. While you wait I recommend you look for an answer yourself, browse the internet. In case you find an answer you can post an answer yourself. In case you find more details, you can incorporate those in an edit to your question in which case it might attract new eyes, or others know better how to help you out.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Okay great. Thanks for giving me hope. I did search online but didn't find anything sufficient enough. Maybe I'll give it another go later when I get free.